# Best way to compare a in a list of list and add a different value with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm importing a CSV that has duplicate values in the second column and add the corresponding values in column 1.

```
64052,10.10.10.10,RED
3802,192.168.10.10,BLUE
488,10.10.10.10,RED
```

I've imported the CSV values to a list of lists as below:

```
import csv

out = open('example1.csv','rb')
data = csv.reader(out)
data = [[row[0],row[1],row[2]] for row in data]
out.close

print data
```

> ['64052', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'], ['3802', '192.168.10.10', 'BLUE'],
>   ['488', '10.10.10.10', 'RED']

What's the best way to go through the lists and if the "second" [1] value matches, add the values "first" [0]?

This would be the expected output I'm trying to accomplish:

> ['64540', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'], ['3802', '192.168.10.10', 'BLUE']

Comment: The statement `if the "second" [1] value matches, add the values "first" [0]` makes no sense whatsoever, and there is no visible relation between the input and the desired output.

Comment: There is a correlation - if the IP matches, add first columns

Comment: Yes, if the IP matches, I want to add values in the first columns.

Comment: What if the IP matches but the colour is different?

Comment: If the IP matches but the color is different the row is representing a different entity and the First Column would need to be totaled against those rows that match both IP and color

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using **pandas** :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([('64052', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'), ('3802', '192.168.10.10', 'BLUE'), ('488', '10.10.10.10', 'RED')], columns = ['Value', 'IP', 'Color'])
# You can import the whole .csv file using the .read_csv() method

df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(int) # Cast to integers
df.groupby(['IP', 'Color']).sum()
```

**Result**:

```
In[39]: df.groupby(['IP', 'Color']).sum()
Out[37]: 
                     Value
IP            Color       
10.10.10.10   RED    64540
192.168.10.10 BLUE    3802
```

Then to retrieve the tuples in a list use the iterator `.itertuples()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to keep track of records:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for row in data:
    key = (row[1], row[2])
    result[key] += int(row[0])
```

Then you result will look like this:

```
{
    ('10.10.10.10', 'RED'): 64540,
    ('192.168.10.10', 'BLUE'): 3802,
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I'll post my final results. Working on outputting the dict to a csv of my orginal format.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (assuming the number at index 0 is a number and not a string otherwise you'd have a convert it into a number)

```
data = [
    (64052,'10.10.10.10','RED'),
    (3802, '192.168.10.10','BLUE'),
    (488, '10.10.10.10','RED'),
]

ip_to_datum_map = {}

for datum in data:
    number, ip_address, colour = datum
    if ip_address in ip_to_datum_map:
        existing_number = ip_to_datum_map[ip_address][0]
        ip_to_datum_map[ip_address] = (existing_number + number, ip_address, colour)

    else:
        ip_to_datum_map[ip_address] = datum

print(ip_to_datum_map.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It worked for me with :
l = [['500', '192.168.10.100', 'RED'],['64052', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'], ['3802', '192.168.10.10', 'BLUE'], ['488', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'],['488', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'],['500', '192.168.10.10', 'RED']]

Output was => [[65028, '10.10.10.10', 'RED'], [4302, '192.168.10.10', 'BLUE'], ['500', '192.168.10.100', 'RED']]

```
data = [['500', '192.168.10.100', 'RED'],['64052', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'], ['3802', '192.168.10.10', 'BLUE'], ['488', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'],['488', '10.10.10.10', 'RED'],['500', '192.168.10.10', 'RED']]


key_l=[]
final_list=[]
l_index=[]
my_dict={}
for i in range(len(data)):
    next_val = i+1
    if next_val > len(data):
        break
    k=i+1
    key_l=[]
    for j in data[i+1:]:
        if j[1] == data[i][1]:
            if my_dict:
                if j[1] in my_dict.keys():
                    k=k+1
                    continue
                else:
                    key_l.append(k)
                    k=k+1
                    continue
            else:
                key_l.append(k)
                k=k+1
        else:
            k=k+1
    if key_l:
        key_l.append(data.index(data[i]))
        #make a dictionary with ip as key and values = indexes from list containing this ip 
        my_dict[(data[i][1])] = key_l

#iterate over each key and add the 0th value of each list element found at data[index]         
for each_key in my_dict.keys():
    new_val = 0
    for value in my_dict[each_key]:
        new_val += int(data[value][0])                

    data[value][0] = new_val
    new_l = data[value]
    final_list.append(new_l)

for val in my_dict.values():
    l_index += val

#add those list elements which are left
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i in l_index:
        continue
    else:
        final_list.append(data[i])

print final_list
```